# Brahmcharyavas : starting, ending

Tags: theravada, reference-request, mahayana, religion, sutta-reference

**Last question**:-
"Bramchariyavas has started" -> "ब्रह्मचर्यवास शुरू हुआ"।

Did this "occur" to anyone in past and the same has been mentioned in books? What are the surrounding indications for the same occurence?

I am open to any religion for its discussion but if outside Buddhism then  it must be accompanied with proper explanation of this statement, work left to be done, resolutions done to move further, path leading to this statement etc.

This might have occurred with few other things like images/world etc. indicating few other things, that's fine but this statement is must, as it is, without any beginning and ending with word "started".

I have read only, `"bramchariyavas has been completed, what needed to be done has been done"`.. this occurred to gotama after achieving enlightenment.

References in bits & pieces are also welcome. Anger looking collections are also welcome.

Comment: One can also start with, "what's the brahmcharyavas that Buddha stated to end successfully?"

Comment: Where did you read that from?

Comment: Are you saying you're only interested in what "brahmacharya" means -- and not interested in the context i.e. what "starting, ending" means?

Comment: @ruben2020 Somewhere in suttas, it's mentioned as brahmcharya, somewhere (like in sutta summaries) as brahmchariyavas. Eg. in sammanya phal sutta (2nd chapter) of dighanikaya. 3 words Brahm/Brahma , charya, vas. In some of ancient Hindu scripts(as per my talks with some of these traditions) charya and modern day vas are almost same, in some charya is qualities, traits, characteristics etc. Vas is living. Brahm and Brahma are different in some and same in some. Brahm and par Brahm are also different in some and same in some.

Comment: For me, I m particularly interested in starting part, cause ending part is mentioned in suttas and if not explained then atleast a path to that is mentioned in form of core Buddha's teachings.

Comment: You mentioned that you've read about "Brahmacharya" being completed after Gotama's enlightenment. That's cool, but I'm afraid I can't find any instances where it was specifically "started" with the exact words you're looking for. Maybe it's out there somewhere, but it's hiding from me like a ninja. So, sorry, man, I can't give you any solid references or angry-looking collections on this one. But if you're into the whole Brahmacharya thing, there's plenty of other stuff to explore!

Answer (score 3):

BRAHMACHARYA can interpret as avoid from sexual activity. because buddha saw sexual or other any desire or bonds cause to SANSARA (rebirth).
therefore monks have to avoid from sexual activity and follow BRAHMACHARYA

Answer (score 0):

> In the same way, brahmin, a Realized One arises in the world, perfected, a fully awakened Buddha, accomplished in knowledge and conduct, holy, knower of the world, supreme guide for those who wish to train, teacher of gods and humans, awakened, blessed. He realizes with his own insight this world—with its gods, Māras and Brahmās, this population with its ascetics and brahmins, gods and humans—and he makes it known to others. He teaches Dhamma that’s good in the beginning, good in the middle, and good in the end, meaningful and well-phrased. And he reveals a **spiritual practice (brahmacariyaṁ)** that’s entirely complete and pure.
>
> A householder hears that teaching, or a householder’s child, or someone born in a good family. They gain faith in the Realized One, and reflect, ‘Living in a house is cramped and dirty, but the life of one gone forth is wide open. It’s not easy for someone living at home to lead the **spiritual life (brahmacariyaṁ)** utterly full and pure, like a polished shell. Why don’t I shave off my hair and beard, dress in ocher robes, and go forth from the lay life to homelessness?’
>
> [MN 27; stock sutta phrase](https://suttacentral.net/mn27/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=main&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin#11.1)

> And what is right action? **Avoiding** killing living creatures, stealing, and **sexual activity** (**abrahmacariyā**).
>
> [SN 45.8; Noble Eightfold Path](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.8/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=main&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)